# error seen while adding Docker Repository to APT sources

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to add docker repository to APT sources on ubuntu 16.04 using ansible scripts :

```
 - name: Add Docker Repository to APT sources
      apt_repository:
          repo: "{{ docker_apt_repository_details }}"
          update_cache: yes
          state: present
      become: true
```

where, docker_apt_repository_details is defined as :

```
docker_apt_repository_details: deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

But, have observed following error, please note that there is no change in ansible scripts done, and this was working fine a month back. Please suggest how to resolve this issue ?

```
module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_soFQp0/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 556, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_soFQp0/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 544, in main\r\n    cache.update()\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py\", line 522, in update\r\n    raise FetchFailedException(e)\r\napt.cache.FetchFailedException: W:The repository 'https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.\r\n", 
21:38:11                "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
```

Here are the sets of tasks which is used before the failed task :

````
- name: Install Python 2.7.12
     raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)

   - name: Install pip
     apt:
         name: python-pip
         update_cache: yes
         state: latest
     become: true
     become_method: sudo

   - name: Update ubuntu image
     apt:
         update_cache: yes
     become: true

   - name: Ensure APT works with https method
     apt:
         name: "apt-transport-https"
         update_cache: yes
         state: latest
     become: true

   - name: Install CA certificates
     apt:
         name: "ca-certificates"
         update_cache: yes
         state: latest
     become: true

   - name: Add official Docker repository GPG key
     apt_key:
         keyserver: "{{ docker_apt_key_url }}"
         id: "{{ docker_apt_key_id }}"
         state: present
     become: true

   - name: Add Docker Repository to APT sources
     apt_repository:
         repo: "{{ docker_apt_repository_details }}"
         update_cache: yes
         state: present
     become: true```
````

Comment: Have you added the apt key for the repository?

Comment: Yes @AKX , apt key is added before this task . here is the ansible task :  ```- name: Add official Docker repository GPG key
      apt_key:
          keyserver: "{{ docker_apt_key_url }}"
          id: "{{ docker_apt_key_id }}"
          state: present
      become: true```

Comment: Is apt-transport-https installed?

Comment: Yes, apt-transport-https is also installed. Have updated the original question with all the tasks executed before the ```Add Docker Repository to APT sources``` task

Comment: Well, the answer is actually simpler than I thought... see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dockerproject.org APT and YUM repos have been shut down:

> Notice: Shutting down dockerproject.org APT and YUM repos 2020-03-31
>   Docker will be shutting down the deprecated APT and YUM repositories hosted at "dockerproject.org" and "dockerproject.com" on the 31st of March 2020.
>
> We noticed that this project is referencing one of these repositories, and recommend updating to use the "download.docker.com" repository to prevent disruption.
>
> More info: https://www.docker.com/blog/changes-dockerproject-org-apt-yum-repositories/

-- https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, please confirm if I need to update  ```deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main``` to ```deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable```

Comment: Installing docker engine also isnt working :  ```docker_package: docker-engine=17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial ``` Please suggest if this also needs to be modified?

Comment: It's `docker-ce`, not `docker-engine`. See https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/

Comment: Thankyou AKX for your help!